# Union of elements of two RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, union, rdd

I would like to do a union of two RDD's in scala. I can't store either of them in memory because they're pretty big.

```
A = {k1->List(A,B,C), k2->List(W,E,Q)}
B = {k1->List(D,E,F), k2->List(E,U,O)}
```

How can i do a union of A and B to get

```
{(A,B,C,D,E,F),(W,E,Q,U,O)}
```

Thanks,
Nancy

Comment: Could you write the real code? Because `.union` does exactly what you are asking for and I fear that your RDDs are different than the ones you have described.

Comment: What i have are two RDD's like this: <key-> List(String)>  And i have sorted them by key.  What i would like to do is a column-union of the two RDD values.  val a3 = a2.map {case (k,v) => k->v.map{case (ki,vi) => vi}}.sortByKey(true)  val a31 = a21.map {case (k,v) => k->v.map{case (ki,vi) => ki}}.sortByKey(true)  a3.union(a31)

Comment: Please update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you simply need a `join`:

```
val a = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("k1" -> List("A", "B" , "C")), ("k2" -> List("W", "E", "Q"))))
val b = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("k1" -> List("D", "E", "F")), ("k2" -> List("E", "U", "O"))))

val combined = a.join(b) // Join by key
  .values  // drop keys
  .map{case (x, y) =>  x ++ y} // Combine elements
```

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This answer matches version 4 of the question. The question has changed since then. I have not deleted the answer as there are some comments about pitfalls using `zip`*

---

You could use `zip`:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq("A", "B", "C"))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq("D", "E", "F"))

val zipped = rdd1.zip(rdd2)
```

which results in

```
scala>zipped.collect().foreach(println)
(A,D)
(B,E)
(C,F)
```

Comment: I doesn't look like something that OP wants. Not to mentions `zip` in Spark is rather tricky.

Comment: @zero323 It matches version 4 of the question - the question has changed since then. In which cases is `zip` tricky?

Comment: Problem with `zip` is that it requires the same number of partitions (easy part) and the same number of elements on each partition (hard part). It works just fine for RDDs emerging from the same lineage but in general is kind of useless.

Comment: @zero323 Thanks for that snippet.